# Найти ближайшие число в двумерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть двумерный массив со временем

```
$mass = array(
array(12.30, 12.39),
array(13.40, 13.59),
array(14.20, 14.30),
array(18.50, 18.55)
);
```

С помощью функции date('H.i') которая возвращает число с точкой. Нужно найти ближайшие верхние число из массива. То есть, сейчас время 13.20 программа должна вернуть второй массив 13.40 и 13.59.

Comment: Что у Вас не получилось? Ответ полностью же соответствует описанию в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно найти:
Если время в диапазоне - то выведется нужный диапазон.
Если время между диапазонами, то выведется следующий диапазон.
Если время больше, чем введённые диапазоны, то выведется "Время больше не найдено".

```php
$mass = array(
    array(12.30, 12.39),
    array(13.40, 13.59),
    array(14.20, 14.30),
    array(18.50, 18.55)
);

$needle = "18.50";

function fing($mass, $needle)
{
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($mass); $i++){
        if ($needle >= $mass[$i][0] and $needle <= $mass[$i][1]){
            return $mass[$i];
        } elseif (count($mass) > $i+1){
            if($needle > $mass[$i][1] and $needle < $mass[$i+1][0]) {
                return $mass[$i];
            }
        } else{
            return 'Время больше не найдено';
        }
    }
}
```